# Foreach loop with ArrayList does nothing

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

I have a problem using a foreach loop with an ArrayList. The ArrayList is initialized in my program in this class :

```
    public class FonctionnementGlobal {

    /**
     * Contient tout le calendrier, séparé en semestres
     */
    public static ArrayList<DateSemestre> liste_semestre = new ArrayList<DateSemestre>();
```

Then elements are added in my function init() :

```
private static void init() throws SQLException{

[...]
GregorianCalendar dateDebutS = new GregorianCalendar(DS_annee,DS_mois,DS_jour);
            GregorianCalendar dateFinS = new GregorianCalendar(FS_annee,FS_mois,FS_jour);
            GregorianCalendar dateRemiseCheque = new GregorianCalendar(RC_annee,RC_mois,RC_jour);
            GregorianCalendar dateDebutCommande = new GregorianCalendar(DC_annee,DC_mois,DC_jour);
            GregorianCalendar dateFinCommande = new GregorianCalendar(FC_annee,FC_mois,FC_jour);
            liste_semestre.add(new DateSemestre(dateDebutS, dateFinS, dateRemiseCheque, dateDebutCommande, dateFinCommande));
```

My problem is when I want to access it in a method in an other class :

```
public class EcranVicePresident {
[...]
private static void ajouterSemestre() throws SQLException {
[...]
for(DateSemestre sem : FonctionnementGlobal.liste_semestre){
                if(debutS.after(sem.getDateDebutS()) && sem.getDateFinS().after(debutS)){
                    dateok = true;
                }
            }
```

The foreach loop does nothing. I don't understand why, whereas I use this ArrayList without any problem in other methods in my EcranVicePresident class ; and when I check with the isEmpty() method, it returns false.
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Are you sure the loop isn't doing anything?...

Comment: Add in a sysout statement inside the foreach loop to see if it is actually not doing anything... potentially the if statement conditions are not being met.

Comment: Yes, when I do a simple System.out.println("a") before the if in my loop, nothing appears...

Comment: Put a statement on the line just before the loop, does *that* print?  I've seen people try to solve problems like this before only to discover that *the entire function* isn't being called and they've spent hours debugging the wrong segment of code.

Comment: In fact yes, it appears, I'm sorry. I'll check for the values of the dates inside my GregorianCalendars.

Comment: Oh I found my error, I'm stupid. I just forgot to put a "!" before my conditions in the if. I'm sorry !

Comment: Since your error was caused by a missing exclamation mark and not any actual code issues, I think this question should be closed due to "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."